# EWS java - Specify the time zone when instantiate the ExchangeService object?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi, microsoft-exchange

I'm using ews-java-api-2.0.jar in my project. I want to specify EST zone. How this can be done in java api? Something like this.

`ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));`